# What is the syntax for preventing scientific notation in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-visual

I wrote the following code to create a bar plot:

```
ords_prods_merge['order_dow'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

The output is a barchart which shows e.g. le6 at the y axis. I want "normal" numbers there, e.g. 6000000.

Can I write something into my line of code to make that happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know of a by-default method of doing that. But customizing tick labels is fairly easy. Refer to this https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.bar(ords_prods_merge['order_dow'].value_counts())
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')    # prevents scientific notation
plt.show()
```